# GoogleApiClient deprecated issue

Tags: java, android-studio, location

I am following a youtube tutorial to build this uber app but its an old tutorial and he uses GoogleApiClient on it. So I am stuck on that code can anyone help me to fix this?
This is his [video](https://youtu.be/M8GZT1EyVZo?list=PLxefhmF0pcPl6gcWvrpTbjGO7rcMWY1jT&t=217) current time that he is using googleApiClient. You guys can understand what I am talking about just watching it.

XML :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Map full code :

```
package com.example.accident;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class CivilianMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient,ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient,OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient;
    Location lastLocation;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_civilian_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
    {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(locationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }
}
```

Issue one here :

```
public class CivilianMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient,ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient,OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener{
```

Comment: If something is "deprecated" then the documentation usually (always?) suggests what to use instead. The [Google APi Client documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-api-client) has a suggestion to use the GoogleApi interface instead, but as I understand it the "old" GoogleApiClient is still fully functional and you can continue following the tutorial, coding, building and testing your app and then later maybe worry about changing to the GoogleApi interface. Unless you want to find some other tutorial or partly deviate from the current one you are following.

Answer (score -1):

```js
package com.example.accident;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class CivilianMapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient,ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient,OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Location lastLocation;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_civilian_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
    {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(locationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       lastLocation = location;
       
       LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
       mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
       mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomToo(12));
    }
}
```

Comment: than you continue your video 13:35

Comment: It doesn't look like an answer to the GoogleApiClient deprecation issue in the question.